# vertical scrolling too far on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have 2 webpages which scroll down much further than they need to. This only happens on a mobile screen in portrait mode. When the mobile is rotated to landscape, the excessive y-axis scrolling doesn't occur, and when I return to portrait mode, the problem is gone ! and the page stops where it should stop.

I have three webpages and this happens only  on two of them.

I'm not sure which is the problem, the css or the html. Here is the css.

thank you very much for your help

```
html,body
{

overflow-x: hidden;

width: 960px; 
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;"
 }
 header{

    position:relative;
    width:auto;
   max-width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0px auto;
}

#logo-container img{
    width:100%; 
    height:auto;
}







.containerspace
{
  width:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative
    max-width:960px;

}

#thespace{
float:right;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
text-align:right;
padding-right:1px;
width:auto;


}



@media (max-width:500px)  
{
html,body
{
width:auto; !important;
overflow-x: hidden; !important;
}


    #containerspace
    {
           float:left;
            width:460px;
            margin: 30px auto;
            position:relative
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;              
    }

    #thespace{
        float:none;
        padding-left:30px;
        font-size:14px;

            }
    #containerspace img{

        width:100%; 
        height:auto;

        }
    #text_column{
        width:auto;
        font-size:14px;
    }

}


@media (max-width:400px) 
{

    #containerspace
    {

            width:300px;


    }





}
```

Here is the  html as well.

```
<body>
<header>
<div id="logo-container">
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/banner.jpg" /></a></div>
</header>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div class="toggleMobile">
            <span class="menu1"></span>
            <span class="menu2"></span>
            <span class="menu3"></span>
        </div>
 <div id='mobileMenu'>
 <ul>
 <li><a href='que/que.html'><span>que es solidwaka?</span></a></li>  
 <li class='last'><a href='con/con.html'><span>contacto</span></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id='cssmenu' style="float:left;width:300px;">
 <ul>
 <li><a href='que/que.html'><span>que es solidwaka?</span></a></li>  
<li><a href='con/con.html'><span>contacto</span></a></li>
<li class='last'><a href='http://wakanegra.org/index2.html'><span>archivo     waka 2009-14</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="the space" -->
<div id="containerspace">
<section id="text_column">
<div id="thespace">
<p></p>
<p>Solidwaka </p>
<p>- proyecto independiente de arte/investigaci&oacute;n y educaci&oacute;n       </p>
<p>2015  </p>
<p><img src="img/solidWaka.png" alt="solidwaka" width="286" height="455" />    </p>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></div>
</div>
</body>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#featured').orbit();
        });
    </script>
 <!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: Please, make a fiddle, or share the html . In your post we aren't able to view what is the problem

Comment: I guess you don't made this mistake (I hope so), but your CSS is incorrect since you added a double-quote after `margin: 0 auto 0 auto;` which make the rest of you CSS incorrect.

Comment: @Zeratops I think the same, I think that's a mistake at time to writting post here. If he has doublequotes in his code, possibly that's the problem

Comment: hello I've added the html above. the webpage is http://wakanegra.org if that is useful. many thanks for this. (I've changed the double quotes)

Comment: seems to be a firefox issue. not problem in Chrome i've discovered.